# Seaborn barplot/catplot with grouped bars where a columns are group elements

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm not sure if this is possible with Seaborn or if I have to transform my data first. I want a barplot (or catplot) with grouped bars. The keypoint is that the elements in the groups are corosponding to column names and not to values.

That is the data

```
   Year  Gin  Beer
0  2016   84    78
1  2017   75    30
2  2018   42    47
3  2019   25    58
4  2020   51    90
5  2021   40    50
```

And that is my desired output:

[image]

From the Seaborn logic "combined" with my logic I would like to do something like this where I specify the column names in `y=` argument.

```
sns.catplot(data=a, x='Year', y=['Gin', 'Beer'])
```

Can I realize it without touching the data or do I have to transform the data somehow?

This is the MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random as rd
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme()

rd.seed(0)

a = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021],
    'Gin': rd.choices(range(100), k=6),
    'Beer': rd.choices(range(100), k=6)
})
print(a)

# sns.catplot(data=a, x='Year', y=['Gin', 'Beer'])
# plt.show()
```

Comment: Your data needs `melt`ed first. Lots of seaborn examples on SO showing this.

Comment: In order to have that you will need to reshape and to have Gin / Beer in the same column, and in another column there respective values. That way, you can include parameter ```hue```, which will give you what you need.

Comment: `ax = a.set_index('Year').plot(kind='bar', rot=0)`

Comment: Otherwise `a = a.melt(id_vars='Year')` and then `ax = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=a, x='Year', y='value', hue='variable')`

Comment: My brain fart: just `ax = a.plot(kind='bar', x='Year', rot=0)`. No need to set index.